# Custom React Native text input with placeholder

Tags: react-native, input, text, placeholder, textinput

I'm trying to style my TextInput placeholder with 2 colors so I've set it up in the following manner.

```
<TextInput
    { ...props }
    style={[styles.textBox]}
>
    {!value && required && 
        <Text style={{ color: placeholderTextColor }}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>*</Text>
            {placeholderText}
        </Text>
    }
</TextInput>
```

This looks fine for the most part but there are a few issues.

The cursor is placed at the end of the placehoderText. And when I type something it is appended to the placeholderText.

How do I stop the Text element inside the TextInput from being an active entity?

Edit
The props being sent are

```
{
    placeholder={'Enter here'}
    placeholderTextColor={'gray'}
    autoCapitalize = 'sentences'
    value={firstName}
    maxLength= {15}
    required={true}
    returnKeyType="next"
    onSubmitEditing={() => this._next ('lastName')}
    onChangeText={(firstName) => updateFirstName ({ firstName }) }
}
```

Comment: I've written this Expo Snack example some time ago. Check it, I hope it helps: https://snack.expo.dev/@zvona/manipulation-textinput-selection

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment, I'll answer here instead!

Please provide more informations what's in `{...props}` inside the `TextInput` props. Make sure you didn't give the `value` prop the value of `placeholderText`.

Comment: I've updated the post to add the props being sent

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` element that you have used inside the `TextInput` is not a `placeholder`. It is an actual text that is being rendered on top of the `TextInput`, which is why the cursor is appearing at the end of the `placeholderText`.

Use the placeholder prop of the `TextInput` to set the `placeholder` text, and use the `placeholderTextColor` prop to set the color of the placeholder text. Then you can use the style prop to apply any additional styling

Here's an updated version of your code:

```js
<TextInput
{ ...props }
style={[styles.textBox]}
placeholderTextColor={placeholderTextColor}
placeholder={required ? * ${placeholderText} : placeholderText}
/>
```

If you want to have different colors for different parts of the placeholder text, you can use a custom component as the value of the placeholder prop, like this:

```js
const Placeholder = ({required, placeholderText}) => (
  <Text>
    {required && <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>*</Text>}
    <Text style={{color: 'gray'}}>{placeholderText}</Text>
  </Text>
);

<TextInput
  {...props}
  style={styles.textBox}
  placeholder={<Placeholder required={required} placeholderText={placeholderText} />}
/>
```

Comment: In my expected output I need the placeholder to have multiple colors. But with this solution, the placeholderTextColor would fix all of the placeholder with one color. Unless I've misunderstood something.

Comment: Please check second solution above